# C Loading large textfile into array

Tags: arrays, c, heap-memory, lookup

I am a bit stuck here.

I need to load about 2 million fixed length strings into a array, the strings are in a textfile each on a line.
The strings are hexadecimal and 40 characters long.

What is the best way to accomplish this in ansi c?

Lookup speed is important.

After the strings are loaded I have to search through the whole array for matches generated by a loop.

I have two file lets say a bigfile and hugefile, both contain hex values (hashes), I loop through the hugefile with this code.

```
....
FILE *file;
if ( (file = fopen(filenamein, "r") ) == 0 )
{
   fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to open file %s\n", argv[0], filenamein);
   exit(1);
}
while ( fgets(keyword, sizeof(keyword), file) != NULL )
{
    if ( ( pos = strchr(keyword, '\n') ) != NULL )
        *pos = '\0';
    ....
}
....
```

After this is need to look for keyword in bigfile, lookuptime is a keyfactor.
From what I have learned so far the file is to big for the stack.

Comment: You have to look through the array for matches on what? The full value? Could you elaborate on what you're doing with this array, ideally with an example? Is it really the text you have to load, or will a numeric representation (from parsing the hex digits) do? What have you tried so far? What isn't working? Where are you stuck? Is this a C question or a C++ question? (These are two very different languages...)

Comment: If it were me, I would suck them up with one fread after finding the size of the file. Then I would sort them with qsort(), and then search them with bsearch.

Comment: You started well, can you use the example in this piece of documentation to take you further? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w0k41tbs.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your specific needs, there may be a way to do this without loading everything in memory. You haven't provided enough information to go down that road.

However, assuming you are going to load everything into memory, I would probably try to convert the lines to binary. If they contain hexadecimal digits, then they could probably converted to integers or long integer, or maybe an array of integers. Integers will use less memory and can be compared faster for faster searches.

Another approach that might make sense is to sort the resulting integers. Even if you decide to store the strings, it might make sense to sort them. Sorted items can be searched using a [binary search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm), which will be many, many times faster than a brute-force search.

Note that sorting will take some time. So that approach only makes sense if you plan to load the data once and then search it quickly many times.

Comment: That would be a pretty big number. Maybe I'd just load the string, sort it using `qsort()`, and the do searches using `bsearch()`.